# Uploading file on google drive, facing issue regarding NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload file on google drive.
Here is my code.

```
NSLog(@"authorizer : %@",self.service.authorizer);
    GTLServiceDrive *driveService = self.service;
    NSLog(@"auth : %@",driveService.authorizer);

    NSString *title = @"myContactList.csv";

    NSString *mimeType = @"csv";

  NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullFilePath error:nil];
    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    GTLDriveFile *metadata = [GTLDriveFile object];
    metadata.name = title;
    metadata.mimeType = mimeType;
    metadata.originalFilename = title;
    metadata.size = fileSizeNumber;

    //    NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:fullFilePath];

    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:file
                                                                                       MIMEType:mimeType];


    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:metadata
                                                       uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    [driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                         GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                         NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"File %@", updatedFile);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

But I am getting error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher uploadFetcherWithRequest:uploadMIMEType:chunkSize:fetcherService:]:
```

Please help to resolve this issue. I am trying last 4 days. But not got any solution.

Comment: Your `mimeType` value is incorrect, try to use `text/csv`. More information about creating files are in the [Drive API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#creating_new_files) documentation.

Comment: Hi @adjuremods, I have tried with text/csv. But still getting same issue. And I have followed this documentation. But I think this is not proper. Can u please help me for resolve this issue?

Comment: how about `text/plain`? There's nothing I can do much with this since I have limited knowledge in iOS at the moment. If you did try out `text/plain`, I'm thinking it will be okay eventhough the file extension is .csv.

Comment: Hi @adjuremods, I have tried with text/plain. But still getting same issue.